# Does SQL Server 2014 Express, with Advanced Services, actually support full text search?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, sql-server-agent

I've installed SQL Server 2014 Express edition, with advanced services. I was hoping to try out the full-text search features. I read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx#Programmability) that full text search is supported by the 2014 express edition. But, after installing and trying to create a full text index, I get an error stating that full text indexes are not support in this version of sql server.

Are full text indexes actually supported or not? Is there a chance I'm installing the wrong version (not advanced services)? I've uninstalled and re-installed two times just to be sure, but same issue both times. I'm positive I'm installing using the advanced services installer.

I'm on Windows 7, 64-bit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is already an **existing answer** posted by Aaron Bertrand for SQL Server Express 2012.

First install SQL Server 2014 Express with **Advanced Services** as you did. Then read Aaron's instructions at:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407337/express-with-advanced-services-cant-create-full-text-index

The short version is that the user interface does not behave properly when setting up full text.  But you can enable and set up Full Text Indexing and Search through T-SQL code.